# How to import another java project package in Intellij and use it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new on java and I'm trying to import a project package in another project in Intellij IDEA. I want to use LSE and LSENode in my second project.

Here's the project with the package (buarque.thiago.dataTypes) I'm trying to import -

[image: Here's the project with the package (buarque.thiago.dataTypes) I'm trying to import]

Here's my second project, that I'm trying to import the first one -

[image: Here's my second project, that I'm trying to import the first one]

Here's my second project modules -

[image: Here's my second project modules]

I've imported the first one package as I found on google

My code -

[image: My code]

Error -

[image: Error]

Comment: Export the project as jar and import that?

Comment: You can do this with build tools like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I saw someone doing it on Netbeans without Maven, does have any way to do it on Intellij?

Comment: There exists a way, but learning a build tool will be a better option, and it's the way all serious software is managed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency). Configure your 2 projects as modules in IntelliJ IDEA project, make one module depend on another.

Comment: I did it [image 3], I guess I don't know how to import it on my second project

Comment: You added a directory, not a module. Add a new module with the properly configured content roots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html, then add this module to the deps of the another module.